# How to remove particular query from url in rust?

Tags: url, rust, query-string

I've been trying to remove the particular query (ex: "remove=me") from the URL but it seems like there is no API for it

```
use url::{Url};

fn main(){
    let mut url = Url::parse("https://www.example.com/foo?id=1&remove=me").unwrap();
    url.set_query(None); // This will remove all the query parameters
    println!("{}", URL);

   // expected result: https://www.example.com/foo?id=1
   // actual result: https://www.example.com/foo
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the `url` crate makes it quite awkward. The query string can only be appended to or cleared. Editing it requires some gymnastics: generating a filtered set of name/value pairs, then clearing and extended the query string.

```rust
let mut url = Url::parse("https://www.example.com/foo?id=1&remove=me").unwrap();

let query: Vec<(String, String)> = url
    .query_pairs()
    .filter(|(name, _)| name != "remove")
    .map(|(name, value)| (name.into_owned(), value.into_owned()))
    .collect();
url.query_pairs_mut().clear().extend_pairs(&query);

println!("{}", url);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3752b71a0ad28103dec81e37fb3e9568)

Comment: Also works without `collect()`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=be925eb2bc41d3a35627065064ee7c6b.